# SQL Query to insert and get price within a range to length

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

Lets say I have a range of length that have different price

```
Length      Price
0 - 10        18
11 - 15       20
16 - 20       30
21 - 40       45
41 - infinity 60
```

How should I store these information in database and how can I retrieve the information when let's say I enter length of `10.625`? How can I get the price of the item with length of `10.625`?

---

I not sure whether I already solved this problem or not

```
priceData.Length_End = Math.Ceiling(priceData.Length);

        string selectStatement = 
            "SELECT Price PriceList2 " +
            "WHERE @Length_End >= Length_Start AND @Length <= Length_End";
```

Then I get the first reader's value

```
SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   price = decimal.Parse(reader["Price_Per_Ton"].ToString());
   break;
}
reader.Close();
```

Please correct me if I was wrong.
Thanks for all the responses!

Comment: @Soner: How did u edit it?

Comment: I just click the `edit` button http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the structure to:

```
len_start    len_end      price
0            10           18
11           15           20
16           20           30
21           40           45
41           infinity     60
```

and run query like:

```
declare @len decimal
set @len= 10.615

select price from table
Where len_start <= @len and @len < len_end
```

if you are going to use NULL as infinity, run this query:

```
select price from table
Where (len_end is not null AND len_start <= @len and @len < len_end) OR 
      (len_end is null AND len_start <= @len)
```

Comment: you can use 2147483647 which is max number for int in sql.
or you can use null, but it will requires some modification on query

Comment: Accept as answer as the answer is almost what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*Well*, I believe you just need to store `Length` and you can use [`BETWEEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) when you want to get `Price` column in your queries. Like;

```
Select Price
From YourTable
Where Length BETWEEN 11 AND 15
```

Here is [`SQL Fiddle Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddd9d/1).

But this structure is ok only if you know maximum and minimum values of `Length` for each range. If you want to store them in database also, you should seperate two different columns your `Length` column. Like;

```
Max_Length | Min_Length | Price
0          | 10         | 18
11         | 15         | 20 
16         | 20         | 30
21         | 40         | 45
41         |            | 60
```

---

```
Select Price
From YourTable
Where Min_Length < 10.625 AND Max_Length > 10.625
```

Comment: how if I only got 10.625 but min and max length are unknown?

Comment: @Therenho What do you mean unknown? Don't you define these limits?

Comment: I mean once I know the length size for instance 10.625, I will straight  away know the price within the range from the database.